# Who is this person with four eyes in OP song?

Tags: parasyte

He appears recently in OP song. Is he an enemy? An ally?

[image: Snapshot of opening song]

Comment: I remember I saw him in manga, pretty sure he was an enemy

Comment: Pretty sure that's not a "person".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how much further the anime series but he looks like this guy,
[image]

> [image]
>  He's [Gotoh (link contain spoiler)](http://kiseijuu.wikia.com/wiki/Got%C5%8D), he's the mayor's confidant and the most powerful parasite of the series